# Webscraping error with selenium in geckodriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, gecko

I am experiencing a connection denied error in Selenium using geckodriver and Firefox novegator:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scripts/only.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver = Firefox(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: connection refused
```

my code:

```
from time import sleep

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('-headless')

profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True

driver = Firefox(options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://google.com/")
print ("Headless Firefox Initialized")
driver.quit()
```